# Determine number of total frames in MediaPlayer JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

Been experimenting with JavaFX and the MediaPlayer class with some great results. Just wondering if anyone has ideas of how to seek to a specific frame number.

I was thinking that it would be possible to calculate the milliseconds per frame and `seek ()` to that duration value, but it doesn't seem like getting the total number of frames from a file is supported.

Next I thought you might be able to use the `getRate ()` method but this only returns a value akin to 1x-8x "encoded" frame rate.

How does one get the duration between encoded frames in a media file? Can it be even done with pure java/javafx without using a separate library? (Please don't suggest open cv or xuggler)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. And didn't find any solution beside xuggler yet.